# Getting connection time out while running Oozie workflow through Java

Tags: java, workflow, oozie

I am getting following error when i try to run Oozie workflow using java

```
IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.validateWSVersion(OozieClient.java:234)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.createURL(OozieClient.java:300)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.access$000(OozieClient.java:71)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:366)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.run(OozieClient.java:547)
at oozieDemo.main(oozieDemo.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

```
OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http:xxxxxxx/oozie");
System.out.println(" connection established....." + wc);

Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH,"hdfs:foo/xxx/workflow.xml");
conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "foo:8021");
conf.setProperty("nameNode","hdfs:xxxx");
conf.setProperty("queueName", "default");
conf.setProperty("appLibLoc","hdfs:/foo/xxx/lib");

String jobId = wc.run(conf);
System.out.println("Workflow job submitted");
```

So here I can see connection is getting established but unable to run the workflow.

I am new to this. So can't figure it out where exactly it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeout means either:

1. URL is incorrect or down, try pinging it.
2. Firewall is blocking it.
3. Default timeout expired.
4. Your internet access is down, which I'm going to assume isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben...URL is correct as i tried pinging that host and i can see the response , even my internet access is UP and running fine :) i feel u r right at 2nd point might my ofc firewall is blocking it...

Comment: I would check if any firewall on your OS or router is blocking the connection. You may need to forward the port you're using.